# React - How to send a custom function from a child to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a custom steps wizard, please find the implementation below:

```
export const Wizard: React.FC<Props> = props => {
const {
    steps,
    startAtStep = 0,
    showStepsNavigation = true,
    prevButtonText = 'Back',
    nextButtonText = 'Next',
    onStepChange,
    nextButtonTextOnFinalStep,
    onNextClicked,
    onPreviousClicked
} = props;
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(startAtStep);

let CurrentStepComponent = steps[currentStep].Component;

const nextStep = () => {
    setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
};

const previousStep = () => {
    setCurrentStep(currentStep - 1);
};

const goToStep = (stepId: number) => {
    const stepIndex = steps.findIndex(step => step.id == stepId);
    if (stepIndex != -1) {
        setCurrentStep(stepIndex);
    }
};

const handlePreviousClick = () => {
    if (onPreviousClicked && typeof onPreviousClicked == 'function') {
        onPreviousClicked();
    }

    previousStep();
};

const handleNextClick = () => {
    if (onNextClicked && typeof onNextClicked == 'function') {
        onNextClicked();
    }

    nextStep();
};

return (
    <article>
        <section>
            <CurrentStepComponent {...props} goToStep={goToStep} nextStep={nextStep} previousStep={previousStep} />
        </section>
        <footer>
            <div className="wizard-buttons-container back-buttons">
                <Button
                    className="wizard-button wizard-button--back"
                    secondary
                    onClick={handlePreviousClick}
                    disabled={steps[currentStep - 1] == null}
                >
                    <i className="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                    {prevButtonText}
                </Button>
            </div>

            <div className="wizard-buttons-container next-buttons">
                <Button
                    className="wizard-button wizard-button--next"
                    onClick={handleNextClick}
                    disabled={steps[currentStep + 1] == null}
                >
                    {steps[currentStep + 1] == null && nextButtonTextOnFinalStep ? nextButtonTextOnFinalStep : nextButtonText}
                    <i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </Button>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </article>
);
```

};

The way I use it is as follows:

```
    const steps = [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: 'Directors and Owners',
        Component: DirectorsAndOwnersStep
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Bank Account',
        Component: BankAccountStep
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        label: 'Company Documents',
        Component: CompanyDocumentsStep
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        label: 'Review and Submit',
        Component: ReviewAndSubmitStep
    }
];

type Props = RouteComponentProps<MatchParams>;

export const EnterpriseOnboardingPage: React.FC<Props> = () => {

    const onNext = () => {
        console.log('Next Clicked');
    };

    const onPrevious = () => {
        console.log('Previous Clicked');
    };

    return (
        <section>
            <Wizard
                steps={steps}
                nextButtonTextOnFinalStep="Submit"
                onNextClicked={onNext}
                onPreviousClicked={onPrevious}
            />
        </section>
    );
};
```

Now here is my problem, within the child components I want to handle what should happen when the user clicks Next, something like onNextClick execute this custom function in the child component rather than performing the default behaviour implemented in the Wizard component.

I've tried setting State in the wizard, "nextClbRegistered", and through a send the "setNextClbRegistered" to children to pass the custom function and execute it, then in the wizard in the "handleNextClick" if there is a function defined execute it. but it's always undefined.

Any ideas what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React is all about data flowing down in the components tree. If you want your `Child` to be able to show and/or modify a shared state between `Child` and `Parent` you should [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and pass it down via `props` to it's `children`

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const [title, settitle] = useState('foo')

    return <Child title={title} setTitle={setTitle} />
}


const Child = ({ title, setTitle}) =>{
     return <input value={title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
}
```

In class based components

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    state = { title: '' }

    setTitle = title => this.setState({ title })

    render(){
        const { title } = this.state
        return <Child title={title} setTitle={this.setTitle} />
    }
}


class Child extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const { title, setTitle } = this.props
        return <input value={value} setTitle={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you now I understand!